# Is today Christmas Eve Eve?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I know it's weird, but I am just curious.  Tomorrow is Christmas Eve.  And today is the eve of tomorrow.

Is it proper grammar to say that today (December 23) is Christmas Eve Eve?

Comment: You could be droll and say that, but it is not a recognised name for the day. Grammatically I would suggest it be written "Christmas-Eve Eve" - that is, the eve of Christmas Eve.

Comment: On Christmas today will be Manubaday.